# pyodbc query timeout foxpro

Tags: python, pyodbc, visual-foxpro

I have a script in python to pull data from an foxpro database using pyodbc however it gets slow at certian points of the day, it nomally takes less then 3 seconds to run but can take upto a minute at points. I would like to limit it to 3 seconds

```
SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 113
connection_timeout = 3
login_timeout = 3
connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Visual FoxPro 
Database;UID=;;SourceDB=Comp.DBC;'
'SourceType=DBC;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;',timeout=login_timeout,attrs_before={SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT: connection_timeout})

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("select from database")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

alot of the documentation mentions to try

```
    connection.timeout = 3
```

but this does not work it breaks the script. 
Whats the simliest way to fix this?

im using mkleehammer/pyodbc to run the query. The code works fine apart from the timeout

Comment: "it nomally takes less then 3 seconds to run but can take up to a minute"  "it gets slow at certain points of the day"  It sounds as though you are experiencing a network throughput or Workstation resource loading issue.    If you BREAK a connection in the midst of a file transfer with a Timeout, you run the distinct possibility of corrupting the Foxpro data table.  With that in mind, make sure you Backup your FP data table(s).  Regardless, it is far better to see if you can resolve the REAL Cause of the delay rather than just haphazardly terminating the transfer.

Comment: Your SQL statement is wrong and would throw an exception. Also if your VFP database is not version 6 or earlier, ODBC driver wouldn't work (latest is for version 6). Also assuming you made a typo here and have a correct and working version of your code, with a simple query like that changing timings suggest network problems. In a real world application you would want to get remote data with a filter instead of pulling the whole table.

Comment: I belive the cause is someone locking the file, the lock disapears afer a second or two but it still waits the minute. The idea being that it waits a few seconds before trying again rather than a minute as speed is key. The data is backed up with zfs every few minutes so data is okay. The query was just an example the real query is working.